# Power series ordinary differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation: $y'' - (\frac2x + x^2)y' + y = 0$

I need to use power series of the form $y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-5)^{n}$ and coefficients up to n=4

Derivatives of y: $y' = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nn(x-5)^{n-1}$ and $y'' = \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nn(n-1)(x-5)^{n-2}$

If I sub them on my ODE I will get:

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nn(n-1)(x-5)^{n-2} - (\frac2x + x^2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nn(x-5)^{n-1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-5)^{n}$ = 0

But, I have no idea what to do with $(\frac2x + x^2)$.

Comment: Multiply the equation by $x$. Then replace $x$ by $u+5$. Then proceed as usual for the power series solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps

Comment: You're welcome. It will still be a bit messy.